# Opening a pop-up windows when app bar is opened in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am looking for a way to open a custom popup when appbar is opened on windows phone 8. What event shall i capture via which i can open the popup along with the appbar. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the StateChanged event of the ApplicationBar. More on this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.statechanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, i tried this in and example and it works there. I successfully opened the system tray when app bar is maximized. However, when i tried this in my app, it didn't work. I'm creating appbar dynamically. code is   ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;
            ApplicationBar.StateChanged += State_Changed;

Comment: Did you debug? Isn't the control going to State_Changed event handler?